# Add values Dynamically to ComboFieldEditor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am doing a preference page in eclipse for my plugin. I need to add values dynamically - at runtime, in the Combo field editor, in my preference page. Is there a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

`org.eclipse.jface.preference.ComboFieldEditor` does not support this.

The source code for this is not very large (220 lines), you could copy it and modify it to do what you want.